# How to map class in different assembly without inheritance each type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there c# ways that can map class from different assembly through media? Media means adapter. So far what I do is to inheritance each domain entity. If there are 40 entities the in domain assembly, I just inheritance that class within application assembly, It created other 40 files or 1 file with all inheritance.  Then use it into other assembly (Infrastructure assembly). It quite repetitive tasks and bloat code. How to shortcut this kind problem? I prefer c# built-in ways than use external library.

Domain assembly
`SiteEntity.cs`

```
namespace Domain.Entities;
public class SiteEntity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Url { get; set; }
}
public class UserEntity {}
```

Application assembly
`MapSiteEntity.cs` single file each entity

```
using Domain.Entities;
namespace Application.Entities;
public class MapSiteEntity : SiteEntity {}
```

Or `MapEntities.cs` single file contains all entity

```
using Domain.Entities;
namespace Application.Entities;
public class MapSiteEntity : SiteEntity {}
public class MapUserEntity : UserEntity {}
```

Infrastructure asssembly
`ApplicationDbContext.cs`

```
using Application.Entities;
DbSet<MapSiteEntity> Sites => Set<MapSiteEntity>();
```

What I want, I create single file like `MapperEntity.cs`. It can translate all type inside folder Entities inside Domain assembly into `MapEntities.cs`

Comment: *"If theres 40 entity in domain assembly"* then, your domain is probably too broad

Comment: @Cid sory, i dont means the real use case. yes, 40 entity is too broad. But what i want to achieve is to structure clean architecture. What i want to achieve is like compiler feature that can map types within folder into inheritance structure with prefix "Map".  So SiteEntity map into MapSiteEntity and inheritance SiteEntity.

Comment: You could try C# source generators, but I wonder why you want this. It seems a waste of resources to copy objects to almost identical objects because that's what's going to happen when everything is generated. If you want to be "clean", make sure that the source assembly is "clean", i.e. has the least possible amount of dependencies, and can thus be reused where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to create an `Interface` which would be parent of all entities.

You would use that interface to directly cast classes. Something like this :

```
public static T Map<T>(ISite site) where T : ISite, new()
 {
    return new T { Name = site.Name };
 }
```

Comment: using this ways? is not make more bloat code? can u try to look my approach in `MapEntities.cs`. its more simple than this. In example if property only 1, how about 5-6 property each entity. I prefer single file with inheritance ways.